# Report only prints first page on SSRS 2008, prints perfect in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

We have a report that prints perfectly for SSRS 2005, but will only print the first page when using SSRS 2008. We have seen issues like this before with other reports.

At the bottom of the report there is a section that has a "list" inside of a "list". Nothing fancy going on. The parent "list" groups on a value called "UnitId". The child "list" groups on a value called "Id" and has "UnitId" set as its parent group.

Some of the things I have already tried is to set the "keep together" property = true and it didn't work. I've also tried setting a couple different "page break" properties on both lists to no avail.

Anybody have any advice on what I should be doing or looking for?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? Have you solved it? If not..... try and make a really simple example of the problem and re-create the basic parts of your report and post the code so we can play with it. I haven't personally experienced that issue (and other people might not have either) but I would be willing to play with it for a minute but I can't re-create your paging issue... thanks.

Comment: I'm having this same issue in SSRS2014 using the ReportExecution2005 service.  It outputs only the first page and the page is not sized to the device settings.  Sure I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

We got the same issue, I've found this post on the MS Site - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/4b1840c7-f48a-4a29-b802-5e2e8d04d5a6

I've not tried it yet, but sounds like the same issue.